# Trial watermark when installing ExtJs 7 GPL version

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I have installed ExtJS 7 GPL version following the instructions received by email

```
npm login --registry=https://sencha.myget.org/F/gpl/npm/ --scope=@sencha
npm install -g @sencha/ext-gen
ext-gen app -a -t moderndesktop -n ModernApp
cd modern-app
npm start
```

When running npm start, I have the following message in the terminal

```
[ext]: ext-webpack-plugin v7.0.0, Ext JS v7.0.0 Commercial Edition
```

When the app opens in the browser, there is an ExtJs Trial watermark added.

I tried to build the app with Sencha Cmd, but the result is quite the same: Sencha cmd outputs a message about GPL licencing, but the watermark is still here !

How can I properly download and install GPL version?

Note that I tried this with Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using Sencha Cmd (`npx sencha app build`), it says correctly *Using GPL version of Ext JS*, but the watermark is still there.

Comment: https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?238836-What-s-with-the-watermark suggests to hide it with CSS, but this doesn't seem a viable solution to me.

Answer (score 3):

They usually forget to remove the watermark when GPL is released. It happened before in both version 5 and 6.

In order to remove it, update the file .\node_modules@sencha\ext-classic-theme-base\sass\etc\all.scss. The $ext-trial property should have a value of false!default;

```
$ext-trial: false!default;
```

If you update the NPM package you will need to set it to true again, but it did not happen to me up to now..

Comment: Don't you remember how you removed it?

Answer (score 1):

The GPL licence allows you to make a copy of the source, modify it, and publish it.

I published a fixed version of the affected package `ext-classic-theme-base`, that removes the watermark.

You can install it by adding this line under `dependencies` in your `package.json`:

```
"@sencha/ext-classic-theme-base": "https://github.com/lmeyer1/ext-classic-theme-base/tarball/master",
```

This will replace @sencha's original faulty package with the corrected one, then run `npm install`.

You can force an update of this package with `npm install -f @sencha/ext-classic-theme-base`. You might need this because this is not a versioned package.

The display of the version by the webpack plugin is wrong, because tthe webpack plugin ignores the existence of the GPL version. The code says:

```
  if (v._resolved == undefined) {
    v.edition = `Commercial`
  }
  else {
    if (-1 == v._resolved.indexOf('community')) {
      v.edition = `Commercial`
    }
    else {
      v.edition = `Community`
    }
  }
```

therefore:

```
[ext]: ext-webpack-plugin v7.0.0, Ext JS v7.0.0 Commercial Edition
```